# hibernate sql query with distinct and order by

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have this query:

```
"select distinct d from Dance d " +
    "inner join d.meisterschaftDances ms " +
    "inner join ms.danceRegistrations dr " +
    "inner join dr.user u " +
    "where (u.id = :userId " +
    "or d.user.id = :userId) " +
    "AND ms.meisterschaft.open = FALSE " +
    "order by ms.meisterschaft.organizer.id, " +
    "d.discipline, d.age, d.category, " +
    "d.class"
```

The logic would be perfect for me but as we know `distinct` is not so easy with `order by`.

I get the same dance several times because the inner join to meisterschaftDances can have several references.

Sadly I dont know how to rewrite my query in such a way that it is working. Can somebody show me an example which would work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-distinct):

> For JPQL and HQL, DISTINCT has two meanings:
>
> 1. It can be passed to the database so that duplicates are removed from a result set
> 2. It can be used to filter out the same parent entity references when join fetching a child collection

You are interested in the second case, so, you need to add the `QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` hint, like below:

```java
List<Dance> dances = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select distinct d " +
    "from Dance d " +
    "inner join d.meisterschaftDances ms  ...", Dance.class)
.setHint( QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false )
.getResultList();
```

*P.S.* But the above approach may be not workable in some hibernate versions due to bugs (See for example [HHH-13517](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13517) and [HHH-13280](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13280))

Comment: I am using quarkus with hibernate 5.5.0 currently so hopefully anything is fixed in this hibernate version already. Many thanks